# "openssl speed rsa" less performant on (normally) better cpu

Tags: performance, openssl, debian, vmware, xen

I'm trying to figure ou why the "openssl speed rsa" gives me worse result on a better cpu

**1st server**: Linux Debian 8 (running a Xen) - kernel: 4.9.0-amd64

`model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 2200.004
cache size      : 30720 KB
flags           : fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mca cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 bmi2 erms rtm rdseed adx xsaveopt ibpb ibrs stibp
bogomips        : 4400.00`

2nd server: Linux Debian 8 (running a Vmware ESXi (I don't know which one yet) - kernel: 4.9.0-amd64)

`model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v4 @ 2.20GHz
cpu MHz         : 2199.058
cache size      : 51200 KB
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm kaiser arat
bogomips        : 4399.99`

Running a "openssl speed rsa" is giving me this (only pasting 4096bits because it's the only relevant for what I want to do):

1st server:

`Doing 4096 bits private rsa's for 10s: **1699** 4096 bits private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 4096 bits public rsa's for 10s: 105493 4096 bits public RSA's in 10.00s`

2nd server:

`Doing 4096 bits private rsa's for 10s: **1229** 4096 bits private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 4096 bits public rsa's for 10s: 78677 4096 bits public RSA's in 10.00s`

What could explain the difference of the keys created (=470 (1699-1229)) ?

Both servers have their cpu with the aes flag.

The only difference I see are the engine available, 1st server has 
"(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine" and the other not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

As stated by @Alexei Khlebnikov, the `openssl speed rsa` command only measures the speed of the rsa sign/verify functions, and these don't use random numbers. Because of that, my original answer doesn't answer the question.

After a quick search, I found that the 1st server has bmi2 and adx instructions, while the 2nd server doesn't. These instructions are used to improve the performance of
Montgomery’s integer multiplication/squaring, that are used in the RSA signing operations. It's hard to confirm that's the reason for the performance difference, but it can be one of the reasons.

Original answer:

To generate RSA keys you need random and large prime numbers. The process to find a random and large prime number consists in:

1. Generate a random number;
2. Check if it's prime;
3. If it's not, repeat.

As you can see, this involves a lot of RNG, and generating good RNG is really slow. So, having a faster RNG means a faster RSA key generation.

Comment: Indeed it makes a huge difference. I've tested with Proxmox VM and I clearly see the difference:
Without:
`
Doing 4096 bits private rsa's for 10s: 1864 4096 bits private RSA's in 9.99s
Doing 4096 bits public rsa's for 10s: 120240 4096 bits public RSA's in 9.98s
`
With:
`
Doing 4096 bits private rsa's for 10s: 2925 4096 bits private RSA's in 9.99s
Doing 4096 bits public rsa's for 10s: 187866 4096 bits public RSA's in 9.99s
`
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CasimirEX If you think I answered your question, consider marking my answer as accepted. If you don't know how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I think, the answer does not answer the question. `openssl speed rsa` command measures signing and verification operations that do not use RNG, not key generation operations that use RNG.

Comment: You are right. I focused in the end of the question "What could explain the difference of the keys created (=470 (1699-1229)) ?", but "keys created" is the wrong interpretation for the "openssl speed rsa" command output. I've checked the openssl speed source code to verify if it uses any rand operations during the benchmark (e.g. pss padding), but it doesn't look so.

Comment: Looks like bmi2 and adx processor instructions can improve the performance of rsa operations, and these instructions can be found only in the first hardware (1st server) that have the higher performance.